# Create accounts in Firebase Auth from custom admin website while I'm logged in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm doing a web application using Angular 8 and [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire).

On my custom website, a user with the admin privilege, can create accounts for other people.

To do this, I have read that I need to:

> Create a second auth reference and use that to create users.
>   **Reason:** if we use our default auth reference, when the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method creates the new user, the
>   user is signed in automatically, overriding our current session (the
>   logged in user on our custom website).

I have tried:

```
  async createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string): Promise<string> {
    // 1. A new auth session
    let secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig, 'Secondary');
    // 2. Create the account
    const user = await secondaryApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    // 3. Sign out the user created
    await secondaryApp.auth().signOut();
    // 4. Make the auth session null to ensure that it's deleted
    secondaryApp = null;

    if (user.user.uid) {
      // User created
      return Promise.resolve(user.user.uid);
    } else {
      // Error
      return Promise.reject();
    }
  }
```

Error received (**happens when I call the method a second time**):

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named 'Secondary' already exists
>   (app/duplicate-app).

My thoughts/steps were:

1. Create a new auth session.
2. Create the user.
3. Sign out the user created.
4. Delete the auth session created.
5. All clear and ready to create a new account in any moment.

What I'm doing wrong?

My goal is to be able to create accounts while I'm logged in on my custom website.

Comment: In general, this will be easier if you invoke a backend to create the account using the Firebase Admin SDK rather than trying to manipulate the client in ways that it was not really intended.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi, thanks for answering my question. So, in another words, can I create a Cloud Function using `firebase-admin` to use the method `createUser`? This is the correct technique to do this? Thanks again. If you want and have time, add the advice as an answer, so I can select it as the solution for future users too.

Comment: You can absolutely do that.  It doesn't really answer your specific question, though, which is about how the client SDK works.  But I would strongly consider using Cloud Functions and the Admin SDK here.

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess is that you get that error message the second time you call your own `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method. The reason for that is that you've already created an app named `Secondary` on the previous call, and didn't remove that app.

The easiest solution is to check if the `Secondary` app already exists before creating it.

```
let secondaryApp = firebase.app("Secondary");
if (!secondaryApp) {
  secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig, 'Secondary');
}
```